# (Quickbooks Online) Triggering Fields to Autopopulate via the API

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm creating invoice records via the Quickbooks API, which is working fine.  But, certain fields that autopopulate in the UI, are not populating when creating via the API (For instance the Invoice # / DocNumber).  Any thoughts on how to force those fields to autopopulate when using the API?

Note: Someone marked this question as unclear.  No idea how an exact question can be made any clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially figured this one out. The DocNumber needs the AutoDocNumber field set to true. Still a few other fields that are not auto populating, though.

The other fields I just decided to pull from the customer record, since they exist there as well.